# MySQL Open and Opened Tables

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I have 81 tables in an innodb database (MySQL).
The data in them amounts to 2GB on disk.
My queries rarely join more than 3 tables together at once. My innodb_buffer_pool size is about 2.1 GB.

Running mysqltuner.pl I get the following !!

[!!] Table cache hit rate: 7% (274 open / 3K opened)

From mysqlreport I see that I indeed have 274 open, have had 3K opened and that my ceiling for open is 400.

However, doing this

```
show status like '%open%'
```

gets this result

```
...
Open_table_definitions      161
Open_tables                 274
Opened_files             150232
Opened_table_definitions      0
Opened_tables                 0
```

Two questions:

1) Shouldn't the "opened tables" say 3K and not zero in the above result from show status like '%open%'?

2) Any advice on what I need to do to remedy this !! i.e. the low table cache hit rate?

Thanks

PS. If it helps, the second !! I have in mysqltuner.pl is this:

[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 29% (35K on disk / 119K total)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Shouldn't the "opened tables" say 3K and not zero in the above
>   result from show status like '%open%'?

YES, result came mostly from SHOW STATUS and SHOW VARIABLES and some basic calculus operations.

> 2) Any advice on what I need to do to remedy this !! i.e. the low
>   table cache hit rate?

Table cache hit is due to:
       1. too few table opened
       2. Total number of table in all databases <<< open table cache size.

Answer (score 0):

1. `show status like '%open%'` shows the status for the current session rather then for the whole MySQL DB([SHOW STATUS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html)). For getting global status, use `show global status like '%open%'` instead.
2. One problem I encountered for mysqltuner.pl is whenever it is run, it opens all the tables in the database, thus increasing the opened_tables statistics. If it is not the case, [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-cache.html) suggested set `table_open_cache` to  * .